# How to access a synced folder from another PC?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, gnote

I want to share my Gnote files between two Ubuntu PCs. Therefore I sync the folder ~/.local/share/gnote to Ubuntu One. But I don't know how to tell Gnote on the other PC to utilize this synced folder.

Comment: I can't find any FAQ's or any documentation for Gnote, am I overlooking it? I did find a Tomboy page that recommends DropBox for this, but I don't know if that helps you. Just an idea: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tomboy

Comment: My question is rather related to Ubuntu One than to Gnote. I just want to know how a synched folder can be accessed from another computer. What I wrote about Gnote is just an example where this Ubuntu One access would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already syncing a folder on Computer 1 with Ubuntu One, you can easily add that folder on Computer 2 with the Ubuntu One app.

Open it and click on the 'Cloud Folders' button. You should see the ~/.local/share/gnote folder from your question there.

Make sure you are seeing all the folders by clicking the small black triangle next to 'My Folders' to expand the list.

[image: expanded list]

This assumes you have already added it on Computer 1, and that at least one sync has occurred. I seem to remember that Ubuntu One may not support [symlinks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man7/symlink.7.html), nor folders outside /home, so watch for that if you have problems.

[image: U1 app screenshot]

I can't find any documentation specific to hidden files, but [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48444/will-ubuntu-one-support-os-settings-sync) seems to indicate it's possible.

I'm also scratching my head wondering how this isn't an exact duplicate, but I can't find this same question on Ask Ubuntu right now. It's a good question anyway.

For completeness, [here is the answer](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/control-panel/) to your question on the Ubuntu One tutorials page, [here is the main tutorials](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/) page, and [here is the FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/) page. Hope this helps and post an update to your question if it doesn't, and I will adjust the answer.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. It is actually exactly as you described. I can also see the synced folder on the Ubuntu One Webpage. So far so good, but what shall I do on Computer 2 to access the synced folder? It is not visible on Computer 2. Seems that only files from the 'Ubuntu One' folder are available on a second computer.

Comment: I added some small details but you likely tried them. You can always try the [nuclear option](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client) or try [filing a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client). I only suggest this because I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Now it works. After a while, the synced folder appeared also on Computer 2 and Gnote files are perfectly synced between Computer 1 and 2 via Ubuntu One.